# MySQL Count time between 2 dates with multiple rows of data

Tags: mysql, timestampdiff

I have a table which contains 2 columns `date_picked_begin` and `date_picked` and there will be multiple rows which contain a date in each.

How do I use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to get the difference in seconds between the dates in all rows of data.

I have tried the following query but it only returns the difference in seconds from the first row. (It's the alias total_picking_waiting_time which is trying to get the total time).

```
SELECT COUNT(pi.pi_id) AS num_picking_waiting_time,
AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, pi.date_picked_begin, pi.date_picked)) AS average_picking_waiting_time,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, pi.date_picked_begin, pi.date_picked) AS total_picking_waiting_time
FROM (SELECT pi_id, type, date_picked_begin, date_picked, picker FROM pickwave_items) as pi
WHERE pi.type = 'Picking (Waiting Time)' AND DATE(pi.date_picked) = '2017-02-25' AND pi.picker = 1
```

Also, I have been assuming that this query was getting the average time between the 2 dates in all rows. Is this the case? With it not returning the total time as I expected I am now thinking that it isn't.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the subquery in the `FROM` is unnecessary.  It adds verbosity to the query and actually slows it down (because MySQL materializes such subqueries).

Then, to get the total picking time, use `SUM()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(pi.pi_id) AS num_picking_waiting_time,
       AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, pi.date_picked_begin, pi.date_picked)) AS average_picking_waiting_time,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, pi.date_picked_begin, pi.date_picked)) AS total_picking_waiting_time
FROM pickwave_items as pi
WHERE pi.type = 'Picking (Waiting Time)' AND
      DATE(pi.date_picked) = '2017-02-25' AND
      pi.picker = 1;
```

Comment: Ah of course SUM. Thank you very much! I will accept the answer when it allows me to. Thank you also for letting me know the sub query is unnecessary, I could have sworn it didn't work correctly without it when I first tried it months and months ago but is returning the same result now so obviously it was :) Thanks again